# Creating Custom Preferences in NetSuite

Tags: customization, netsuite

I have searched and had no luck on this issue.  In NetSuite I have some Custom Preferences (Setup -> Company -> General Preferences -> Custom Preferences).  I need to create a new group of these, for a project I'm setting up.  I can not find anything in the SuiteAnswers, and the NetSuite support was completely baffled that these even exist.

I'm hoping that someone else on here has had to create some before.  Even if it is just to direct me to an article that I may have missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create them manually. What happens is that the groups are created when an installed bundle has company level parameters

Comment: Okay, That makes sense.  But, then, how do you create company level parameters in a bundle?

Comment: Just create the script parameters and mark them as company level.

Comment: wow...  I've messed with a LOT of scripts and I never noticed that Company/User preference...  (facepalm).  Thanks...  :)